# How to customise the php script so that the feedback is exactly the same as the user have typed out in a form?

Tags: php, forms

Does anyone have any idea how to customize the php page so that the user can see a feedback of what he has already filled in? I noticed many php scripts have a 'thank you' feedback but I want more than that. The codes for the php as shown below :

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "james@ace.com.sg";

    $email_subject = "Photography Courses that I want to sign up";


    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['tel']) ||

        /*!isset($_POST['basic']) ||

        !isset($_POST['advanced']) ||

        !isset($_POST['raw']) ||

        !isset($_POST['lightroom']) ||*/

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      

    }




    $name = $_POST['name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['tel']; // required

    $basic = $_POST['basic']; // not required

    $advanced = $_POST['advanced']; // not required

    $raw = $_POST['raw']; // not required

    $lightroom = $_POST['lightroom']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required


    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

     $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";


   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }


  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

 /*if(!preg_match($string_exp,$telephone)) {

    $error_message .= 'You need to insert the telephone number.<br />';

  }*/


 /* if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'Insufficient Words for comments! <br />';

  }*/

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "\n Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Courses Taking: \n\n".clean_string($basic)."\n\n" .clean_string($advanced)."\n\n" .clean_string($raw)."\n\n" .clean_string($lightroom)."\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n\n";


// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->
 <?php


 echo '<h2>Thanks for filling up this form, We will get back to you by next Monday (29 Sep). Have a terrific weekend!</h2>';

echo '<p>**How do I feedback of what the user has already filled in the form here?** </p>';


 ?>


 <?php
$redirect = 'http://www.acetraining.com.sg';
?>

<?php

}

?>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
redirTime = "4000";
redirURL = "<?php echo $redirect ?>";
function redirTimer() { 
self.setTimeout("self.location.href=redirURL;",redirTime);}
</script>
<BODY onLoad="redirTimer()">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Well actually I want the particulars of the respondent to be within the success HTML portion :



<!-- include your own success html here -->
 <?php

 echo '<h2>Thanks for filling up this form, We will get back to you by next Monday (29 Sep). Have a terrific weekend!</h2>';

echo '<p>**How do I feedback to the user of what the user has already filled in the form here?** </p>';


 ?>

Thanks!

Comment: OK. I want the result to look something like this :

Thanks for filling up the form. This is the confirmation of what you had filled up :

Name : James

Email : clavin007@gmail.com

Tel : 612233445

Courses : Advanced Photoshop CC for Photographers - 14 Nov (Fri)

Right now, the feedback that the user sees after filling up is "Thanks for filling up this form. We will get back to you by next Monday (29 Sep). Have a terrific weekend!". I don't want this. I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Variable for date in your `if(isset)` condition. after this line

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$date=date("j M \(D\)");

    $date2=date("l \(j D)", strtotime($Date. ' + 3 days'));
//I added Three days. You can its +3, you can add any number of days. its up to you
```

Read you last commment its according to that.

**I want the result to look something like this**

```
    echo 'Thanks for filling up the form This is the confiermation what had filled up:' .
'<br/>'. 'Name: '.$name.' Email: ' .$email_from.' Tel: '. $telephone .' Courses: '.
 $advanced. ' '.' - '.$date.' Right Now';
```

**the feedback that the user sees after filling up is**

```
echo 'Thanks for filling up the form We will get beck to you by next '. $date2;
```

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt response. I do not want to customize the error message. For example, if the person fills in the form as the name as James and his email as clavin007@gmail.com. Upon clicking on the send button, I want the php form to output as his name as James and email as clavin007@gmail.com. This is a kind of confirmation rather than just display a thank you message.  

Sorry, I am not too good in php and I don't quite understand the codes. Is it anyway you can help me with the existing codes that I have provided?  Cheers!

Comment: Yes! I managed to edit successfully. Thanks a lot for your prompt response. You have been a great help! 

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, how do you accept the answer? Is there a special button I click on?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping. I have managed to solve the problem. This is what I had done in the php page.

```
echo '<h2>Thanks for filling up the form. This is the confirmation of what you had filled up:<br/><br/>' .'<br/>'. 'Name: '.$name.'<br/><br/>'.' Email: '.$email_from.'<br/><br/>'.'Tel: '.$telephone.'<br/><br/>'.' Courses: '.$basic.'<br/><br/>'.$advanced.'<br/><br/>'.$raw.'<br/><br/>'.$lightroom.'<br/><br/>'.' Comments: '.$comments.'<h2>';
```

It's working fine now!